# Integration grapes with React

Tags: reactjs

How can I integrate grapejs with ReactJs, react dom is not rendering the grapes content inside it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';

class TemplateEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      template: null,
      editor: null,
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.editor == null) {
      let editor = grapesjs.init({
        container: '#gjs',
        fromElement: true,
      });
      this.setState({editor})
      console.log(editor);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <main>
        <div id="gjs" ref={el => this.el = el}></div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default TemplateEditor;
```

I am adding stylesheet directly to html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called setState after creating the editor. ReactDOM will re-render the component and replace the div container which has id #gjs by a new one so that you can not see the editor rendered.

To use GrapesJS in React. You have to call `editor.render()` to get the dom content of the editor and render it by using dangerouslySetInnerHtml.

However, you may use this package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/grapesjs-react` to easy embed Grapes JS editor into React component